# Chrony lose connection with local host after 10 minutes

Tags: rhel, ntp

I'm trying to configure chrony on RHEL 7.4. I configured the local clock (127.127.1.0) as a source, and chrony get time from it for about 10 minutes and then chrony stops receiving packets from it ('chronyc sources' shows 0 packets reached), although using tcpdump shows that ntp packets are sent to the local clock and back to localhost (also running 'chronyc ntpdata' shows it does not get time from the local clock).
My chrony configuration:

```
server 127.127.1.0 iburst
peer 192.168.11.7 iburst
local stratum 10
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
makestep 1.0 3
rtcsync
```

'chronyc sources' while it works:
[image]

After 20 minutes:
[image]

Also using tcp dump I figured that after starting chrony the packets from 127.127.1.0:123 looks correct, stratum and reference-id looks good, and after a few minutes the stratum written in the packets grow up to 15 and then all the later packets have "Stratum 0 (unspecified)" and also "Reference-ID: (unspec)".

Any ideas?

Comment: I use chrony, not ntpd...

Comment: sorry `chronyc sources`

Comment: I added the results

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about programming.

Comment: your actual server `192.168.11.7` is unreachable.... diagnose that first and take some time to read up on how the `ntp` protocol works.

Comment: it is unreachable because the server is off (it's mine). It is reachable and works well when it is on. The issue here is the local machine clock working at first and then stops working.